# Prebuild of static library failed

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

I try to set up an Android NDK build based on CMake scripts, which dynamically create the required Android make files. While I can't use the JNI folder structure I split the build process in several separated make scripts:

1st Create root Android.mk file located in project root:

```
#ANDROID ROOT MAKEFILE

LOCAL_PATH := D:/binrev/repository/bar
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

MY_LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DDEBUG
include D:/binrev/repository/bar/src/Android.mk
```

2nd Create source Android.mk file in project source folder and perform module build:

```
$(info "[INFO] Source Makefile invoked")

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := bar
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= D:/binrev/repository/bar/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  bar.cpp

ifeq (debug,"debug")
   MY_LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DDEBUG
endif

ifeq (false,true)
   LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
endif

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := D:/binrev/repository/bar/include

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += foo 

ifeq (OFF, ON)
   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
else
   include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
endif
```

Basicly this mechanism works and I could compile my sources, but I fail if I try to include a Prebuild of a library. I tried the following ways to include a pre-build
of a static library (with modified source/include definitions):

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/android/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfoo.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

1st Prebuild definition in source Android.mk file
2nd Call import-module mechanism and add Prebuild Android.mk file to prebuild-lib
3rd Prebuild definition in root Android.mk file

[Edit:] Here is the snipped of the call-import test which also fail:
    $(info "[INFO] Source Makefile invoked")

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := bar
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= D:/binrev/repository/bar/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  bar.cpp

ifeq (debug,"debug")
    MY_LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DDEBUG
endif

ifeq (false,true)
    LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
endif

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := D:/binrev/repository/bar/include

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += foo 

ifeq (ON, ON)
   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
else
   include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
endif

$(call import-module, external-deps/foo)
```

In each case the Script with the prebuild-definition is invoked, but the prebuild
is not performed. When my NDK build has been compleded, the prebuild library and
objects are not copied to my obj folder. It seems to me that the prebuild is 
completely ignored. But the path to prebuild sources are correct, otherwise the
compile fails with missing file error.

You could get the complete source of this test implementation here:
[Test projects][1]https://sourceforge.net/projects/binrevengine/files/publications/

Hint: The bar project is the project which tries to prebuild the foo project. 
      The foo project contains the prebuild sources.

The added tests projects could be build by your own using MinGW64 with GCC 4.7/4.8 in handshake with CMake and pre installed NDK (using r8e).

I completly get lost and running out of ideas ...
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The Android build system will not build a static library without it being used by a shared library.  Just create a dummy shared library that has your static library as a dependency and voila:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := dummy
LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := dummy.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := foo
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: The bar project is build as shared library which references the foo project.

Comment: I've edited the source sample and add the make file of the call-module import test.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude possible sources of defects I've reduced the Android make file to simplest case without using CMake generator of those files:

```
LOCAL_PATH := D:/binrev/repository/bar
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := foo-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := external-deps/foo/lib/android/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfoo.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)           
LOCAL_MODULE    := bar
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= D:/binrev/repository/bar/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES+= D:/binrev/repository/bar/external-deps/foo/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/bar.cpp


LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid 

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := foo-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and:

```
LOCAL_PATH := D:/binrev/repository/foo

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := foo
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= D:/binrev/repository/foo/include
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/foo.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid 

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

The failure still exists. The prebuild of the foo library is not executed. I also excluded MinGW64 as possible source of defect, if I try to build the project with Windows command line it results in same issue. The shared library is build, but the prebuild is not executed.

I checked my sources and scripts multiple times, but can't find any failure.
Any ideas what could be wrong or missing?